# Bluetooth not working - Ubuntu 16.04 Toshiba L50D-C

Tags: bluetooth, toshiba

I got an bluetooth icon, I can turn it on and off, i can make it hidden or not and there are preferences. When I press Device search, laptop can not find any device. I tried several phones, headphones and SONY external bluetooth speaker. I have dualboot with windows, at windows working very well.
After several days I found this page:
[toshiba-satellite-c50d](http://www.linlap.com/toshiba_satellite_c50d)

I think there is a problem with ubuntu support :( but maybe some forum guru can help me anyway.

There are some my code sample exports:

```
andrej@andrej-ubuntu:~$ lspci | grep Net; lsusb
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 145f:01c8 Trust 
Bus 002 Device 032: ID 0bb4:0001 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) Android Phone via mass storage [Wiko Cink Peax 2]
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0930:0222 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 13d3:5652 IMC Networks 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

andrej@andrej-ubuntu:~$ ps aux| grep bluetooth
root       824  0.0  0.0  32084  4564 ?        Ss   11:26   0:00 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
andrej    1362  0.0  0.1 349412  8052 ?        Ssl  11:26   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-bluetooth/indicator-bluetooth-service
andrej    1751  0.0  0.1 150340 10080 ?        S    11:26   0:00 /usr/lib/bluetooth/obexd
andrej   13460  0.0  1.2 1080024 99436 ?       Sl   21:10   0:01 unity-control-center bluetooth
andrej   13469  7.9  0.4 623696 32496 ?        Sl   21:10   1:24 bluetooth-wizard
andrej   14192  0.0  0.0  14356   972 pts/0    S+   21:28   0:00 grep --color=auto bluetooth

andrej@andrej-ubuntu:~$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    AC:E0:10:EC:A1:F8

andrej@andrej-ubuntu:~$ cat /var/log/dmesg
(Nothing has been logged yet.)

andrej@andrej-ubuntu:~$ start bluetooth
start: Unknown job: bluetooth

andrej@andrej-ubuntu:~$ bluetoothd -d -n
bluetoothd[13953]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
bluetoothd[13953]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing main.conf
bluetoothd[13953]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'DiscoverableTimeout' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[13953]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'PairableTimeout' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[13953]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'AutoConnectTimeout' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[13953]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'Name' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[13953]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'Class' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[13953]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'DeviceID' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[13953]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'ReverseServiceDiscovery' in group 'General'
D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.456" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file
bluetoothd[13953]: Unable to get on D-Bus

andrej@andrej-ubuntu:~$ lsmod | grep -i toshiba
toshiba_acpi           40960  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 toshiba_acpi
toshiba_bluetooth      16384  0
wmi                    20480  1 toshiba_acpi
video                  40960  1 toshiba_acpi

andrej@andrej-ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    2.875630] usb 2-2: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    6.573584] toshiba_bluetooth: Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device driver
[    6.668772] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    6.668797] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.668805] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.668810] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.668819] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    7.438022] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.438027] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.438033] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   12.118434] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   12.118444] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   12.118453] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

andrej@andrej-ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    1.138689] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.212214] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    2.459485] [drm] Found UVD firmware Version: 1.64 Family ID: 11
[    2.460350] [drm] Found VCE firmware Version: 50.17 Binary ID: 3
[    2.945890] psmouse serio2: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x5e1f02)
[    6.737690] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin

andrej@andrej-ubuntu:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [1179:f840]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b730]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be

andrej@andrej-ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux andrej-ubuntu 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

andrej@andrej-ubuntu:~$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: AC:E0:10:EC:A1:F8  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:7405 acl:0 sco:0 events:1268 errors:0
    TX bytes:12440 acl:0 sco:0 commands:1069 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'andrej-ubuntu'
    Class: 0x1c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0xb
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x8723
    Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)

andrej@andrej-ubuntu:~$ rfkill list
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

andrej@andrej-ubuntu:~$ lsusb -s 002:003 -v

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0930:0222 Toshiba Corp. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass          224 Wireless
  bDeviceSubClass         1 Radio Frequency
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Bluetooth
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0930 Toshiba Corp.
  idProduct          0x0222 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          177
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              4 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              4 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0000  1x 0 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0000  1x 0 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              4 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0009  1x 9 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0009  1x 9 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       2
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              4 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0011  1x 17 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0011  1x 17 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       3
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              4 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0019  1x 25 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0019  1x 25 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       4
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              4 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0021  1x 33 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0021  1x 33 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       5
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              4 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0031  1x 49 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0031  1x 49 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

can somebody help me with this problem?